# Related to payment system in Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I haven't done payment implementation yet I am just reading about its implementation process ,so I need some help related to payment system implementation with Paypal so for it first I wanted to know in paypal payment is there paypal charges for  each transaction of payment & whom will pay for it like is that Primary user pay for transaction or secondary user pay for it ?
   Because we have to implement recurring payment for subscription plan.
So I need help in  topic 1.who will pay for paypal on every transaction
2. recurring payment & its some code of implementation
Please help me on these topic & guide me appropriate content for its implementation.
Thanks in Advance !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

PayPay does have fees located here [PayPal Fees](https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/paypal-fees), It states the sender usually chooses who pays the fees - when sending or recieving, not selling!

Answer (score 0):

Just like CygnusH33L stated, PayPal has all fees published online.

The receiver (seller) pays the fees for the transactions. Anyone purchasing your items or subscribing to your service does not pay an additional fee (unless there is a currency conversion involved). If you are the receiver of the funds for business transactions you will pay the fees.

If you need to create a subscription button, here is the link:
[Subscription Button Developer Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons)

This guide gives you the HTML Code and everything that is needed for creating subscription buttons.